# How do you use ImageJ to measure the columnarity of the cells?

Tags: imagej

So, I have an .czi file, which is an image of some cells. It has several z-stacks. What I want to do is to measure their columnarity, i.e., I want to be able to "transform" that image so that, instead of looking at the cells from above, I can look at them from one side (and thus, see if their columnar or not).

I've tried the reslice option, but, with the final image it gives me, I find it very difficult to see when does a cell ends and when does the next one starts.

Is there any other option I could use? Or can I do any other processing to the resliced image so that it is clearer?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Select *Image > Stacks > Orthogonal Views* (Mac shortcut is cmd + shift + H) this will present the YZ and XZ views to the right and bottom of the XY view. Use the cursor to move the yellow crosshairs to any cell you'd like to examine.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I tried it and orthogonal views are even less clear than the resliced image.